# How to show titles as links using JSOUP

Tags: java, android, oracle, parsing, jsoup

Recently I was trying to build my own android app using JSOUP. I faced with the problem of showing titles from news as links. I mean I did created small application which shows the headlines of news portal, but it is only text. Is it possible to show this text as clickable links, so that in will navigate to the web view page of an article?

Here is the extract from the code:

`public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public Elements title;

public ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    new NewThread().execute();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, titleList);
}


public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {


        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://tech.onliner.by/").get();
            title = doc.select(".b-posts-1-item__title");
            titleList.clear();
            for (Element titles : title) {
                titleList.add(titles.text());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}`
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO! while you explain your problem quite well, it would help a lot if you'd include a bit of code, explain what you have tried and where you got stuck. It'll help others to give you a relevant and more specific answer to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. Added the code example

Answer (score 0):

Set an OnItemClickListener to handle click events in your listview, then create an Intent to launch your webview activity passing the url you want view as data.

```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String url = ...; //The url
        Intent i= new Intent(...); //The activity, flags...
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));

        startActivity(i);
      }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please provide which exactly Imports should i set in order to execute such extract of code&

Answer (score 0):

I agree with eltabo's approach however it requires another activity to launch the url

A different approach would be to launch the url on clicking the listview from the same activity without passing it to another one for webview launch

This technique can be implemented using HashMap

1) Add the title and the link to HashMap

```
hashMap.put(title,url);
```

2) Next in the listview onClickListener we add the code to launch the corresponding url

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {}
```

we can make use of the position of the listview item clicked and use it to retrieve the corresponding url from the HashMap

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
                        value=(new ArrayList<String>(hashMap.values())).get((int)arg3); // based on position clicked retrieve the value ( the url for the title) from hashMap
                        Uri uri=Uri.parse(value); // here we parse the url
                        startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", uri));
        }
```